# Flutter callbacks - Removing a widget in a list from child

Tags: flutter, callback, flutter-layout

I have this app where you type in some text and press a button which adds this text to a custom widget. Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count = 0;
  TextEditingController noteSend = TextEditingController();
  List<String> noteString = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = new List.generate(
        count,
        (int i) => new InputWidget(i,
            noteRec: noteString[i], noteString: noteString, count: count));

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('some title')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: noteSend,
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              width: 150,
              height: 50,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: children,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              noteString.insert(
                noteString.length,
                noteSend.text,
              );
              count = count + 1;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
}

class InputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String noteRec;
  final List<String> noteString;
  final int count;

  InputWidget(this.index, {Key key, this.noteRec, this.noteString, this.count})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputWidgetState createState() => _InputWidgetState();
}

class _InputWidgetState extends State<InputWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        //                            <-- onLongPress
        setState(() {
          widget.noteString.removeAt(widget.index);
        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  size: 75,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 30),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Note'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("${widget.noteRec}"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to wrap the custom which in a gesture detector and then add a onLongPress which removes the widget at the index but it's not working.
How can I remove the widget I long press on ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, you'll need to use a callback.  Because of the scope of the variables, you can't directly delete a variable from noteString in the InputWidget() due to scope, however, it HAS to be triggered by InputWidget because the index information is contained in that widget and has to be used to remove the items from the noteString List, as well as removing the InputWidget from the children List.  Therefore, it's callback time.

Callbacks work like this: 
1. define a variable that will receive a function in the child.

```
final Function(int) onDelete;
```

2. Call the function in the child and pass in the needed variable:

```
onLongPress: () {
        widget.onDelete(widget.index);
      },
```

3. Define the function in the parent THAT YOU WANT TO USE IN THE PARENT and then pass it to the child:

```
Function(int) onDeleteVar = (int val) {
  setState(
    () => {
      noteString.removeAt(val),
      count--,
      children.removeAt(val),
    },
  );
};

children = List.generate(
    count,
    (int i) => new InputWidget(i,
        noteRec: noteString[i],
        noteString: noteString,
        count: count,
        onDelete: onDeleteVar));
```

Here's a dartpad to see it in action:
http://dartpad.dev/a25e9c402a90fefc778bcfac27aee242

And here's the code:

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count = 0;
  TextEditingController noteSend = TextEditingController();
  List<String> noteString = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children;
    Function(int) onDeleteVar = (int val) {
      setState(
        () => {
          print("noteStringBefore: $noteString"),
          print('childrenBefore: $children'),
          print(val),
          noteString.removeAt(val),
          count--,
          children.removeAt(val),
          print("noteStringAfter: $noteString"),
          print('childrenAfter $children'),
        },
      );
    };

    children = List.generate(
        count,
        (int i) => new InputWidget(i,
            noteRec: noteString[i],
            noteString: noteString,
            count: count,
            onDelete: onDeleteVar));

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('some title')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: noteSend,
              ),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              width: 150,
              height: 50,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: children,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              noteString.insert(
                noteString.length,
                noteSend.text,
              );
              count = count + 1;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
}

class InputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String noteRec;
  final List<String> noteString;
  final int count;
  final Function(int) onDelete;

  InputWidget(this.index,
      {Key key, this.noteRec, this.noteString, this.count, this.onDelete})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputWidgetState createState() => _InputWidgetState();
}

class _InputWidgetState extends State<InputWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        //                            <-- onLongPress
        widget.onDelete(widget.index);
      },
      child: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.image,
                  size: 75,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 30),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Note'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("${widget.noteRec}"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi William, thank you very much for your reply and explanation. The dartpad you created deletes the note at the end and then when added notes after deletion, it recreates the deleted ones before adding the new one. How can i delete the one I click and stop this issue with recreating old ones? Thank you again

Comment: I updated my answer.  I left out a variable from setState()

Comment: also, I noticed that you use "new" a lot in your code.  The requirement for them was removed a while back, so you don't have to use them anymore.

Comment: I'm getting the error that local variable 'children' cant be referenced before it is declared?

Comment: Oh okay never realised the 'new' was not required thank you for the tip!

Comment: You probably have a cached version of the dartpad, so you'd have to do a hard refresh of your browser.  Just in case, I'll post the code in my answer

Comment: Hi William sorry to bother but I am facing an issue with this callback in my code. If you have any free time I would greatly appreciate you checking it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950659/removing-item-from-list-flutter Thanks

Comment: no problem.  I added my two cents to your question... but without more info, it will be hard to help.  If you'd like, we could start a chat

Comment: A chat would be helpful, how do we start one of these?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210702/flutternoobwterrill