# Removing item from list Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a function which updates elements of a widget. It updates all lists apart from the note list which adds the new element but does not delete the old one. Here is the code where I callback a function which takes the value at index, removes it and then adds the new value and then navigates back to a different page:

```
  Function(int) onEditExercise = (int val) {
      setState(
        () {
          print(val);
          print("repExListBefore: ${widget.repExList}");
          widget.repExList.removeAt(val);

          print("freqListBefore: ${widget.freqList}");
          widget.freqList.removeAt(val);

          print("holdForListBefore: ${widget.holdForList}");
          widget.holdForList.removeAt(val);

          print("noteStringBefore: ${widget.noteList}");
          widget.noteList.remove(val);

          widget.repExList
              .insert(val, _currentRepExSelected ?? widget.repeatEx);
          widget.holdForList
              .insert(val, _currentHoldForSelected ?? widget.holdF);
          widget.freqList.insert(val, _currentFreqSelected ?? widget.freq);
          widget.noteList.insert(val, _notes.text);
          print("repExListAfter: ${widget.repExList}");
          print("freqListAfter: ${widget.freqList}");
          print("holdForListAfter: ${widget.holdForList}");
          print("noteStringAfter: ${widget.noteList}");

          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return EditScheduleScreen(
              repExList: widget.repExList,
              holdForList: widget.holdForList,
              freqList: widget.freqList,
              noteList: widget.noteList,
              imageURLList: widget.imageURLList,
              videoURLList: widget.videoURLList,
              count: widget.count,
              therapistName: widget.therapistName,
              name: widget.name,
            );
          }));
        },
      );
    };
```

This is the result from the prints after changing the first widget's values for all lists:

```
flutter: 0
flutter: repExListBefore: [1 time, 1 time, 1 time]
flutter: freqListBefore: [Once a day, Once a day, Once a day]
flutter: holdForListBefore: [10 seconds, 10 seconds, 10 seconds]
flutter: noteStringBefore: [a, b, c]
flutter: repExListAfter: [2 times, 1 time, 1 time]
flutter: freqListAfter: [Twice a day, Once a day, Once a day]
flutter: holdForListAfter: [20 seconds, 10 seconds, 10 seconds]
flutter: noteStringAfter: [change ‘a’, a, b, c]
```

The same code works when i remove a widget entirely in another page:

```
    Function(int) onDeleteExercise = (int val) {
      setState(
        () {
          print(val);
          widget.repExList.removeAt(val);
          widget.freqList.removeAt(val);
          widget.noteList.removeAt(val);
          widget.holdForList.removeAt(val);
          widget.imageURLList.removeAt(val);
          widget.videoURLList.removeAt(val);
          children.removeAt(val);
          widget.count--;
        },
      );
    };
```

Any ideas why it is not working in onDeleteExercise but not on onEditExercise
Thank you

Comment: So what you are passing as the "val" is the position on the list, not the object itself, right? By the way, that is the most complex way I've seen a method being declared in Dart.

Comment: The val is the index that is sent from the current widget clicked, Sorry forgot to mention. I've updated the question because I realised it works somewhere else. Thanks

Comment: This is one of those cases where the complete code would be very helpful... or at least a pared-down version of your code where you're actually seeing the problem.  I don't see anything wrong with your code per se... but I can't see the results of the print statements (i.e. print(val),  print("noteStringBefore: ${widget.noteList}"), etc)  If you can't pare down your code, then you should at least put more print statements in your code using the same "before/after" mentality that you used before.  Without that, it will be difficult to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @WilliamTerrill I added more print statements

Comment: since only noteList is bad, can you use this code to print out logs?

Comment: print('val: $val');
         
          print("noteListBefore: ${widget.noteList}");
          widget.noteList.remove(val);
          print("noteListAfter: ${widget.noteList}");
          print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
          

          print('widget.noteList before: '${widget.noteList});
          widget.noteList.insert(val, _notes.text);
          print('val: $val');
          print('_notes.text: ${_notes.text}');
          print("noteListAfter: ${widget.noteList}");
          print("---------------------------");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having problems with noteList is that you're using .remove() instead of .removeAt() at this line:

```
print("noteStringBefore: ${widget.noteList}"); 
widget.noteList.remove(val);   // this should be .removeAt(val)
```

I made a dartpad here so you can play with it:

https://dartpad.dev/81889b830d6a37873d449c8d143d0f71